# What is for HTTP checksum? And how get rid them?

Tags: http

I repeatedly seen CRC in server response page. 
Usually it come when received data too large. 
It seen like `\r\nf87\r\n` in page. 
Just now I use regexp for delete it. 
But may be isset more accurate solution like send a correct http header?

Thanks for answers and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably seeing [Chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

Do the HTTP responses that show what you are seeing all have `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` headers?

Comment: Nope, but is strange header: "Сontent-encoded entity body (gzip): 1423 bytes -> 28889 bytes" it when i snuff in wireshark.
Suggest it is what i needed. thx

Comment: @unlimited: This is really an HTTP header?  It looks to me more like Wireshark annotation.  Where exactly are you getting this data from?

Comment: likely yes, it is wireshark data. Here server headers:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 30 Oct 2011 12:56:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7.3
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1423
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Sounds like maybe the server is misbehaving and sending chunked responses but saying they are with `Content-Length`?  Are those extra `\r\nf87\r\n` sequences present in the gzipped or uncompressed content?  If you add up all those sequences (converting hex to decimal), do you get a number that matches up with the content size either before or after decompression?

Comment: In uncompressed, really \r\n is space symbols. I get it on ubuntu 11.04 server with apache2 from repository

Comment: And is there a `0` (zero-length) chunk sequence at the end?  I really can't explain why you are seeing this behavior - you'll probably have to dig into the server, but it still sounds a lot like chunked responses.  Try to see what you can find on the server-side.  Good luck!

Comment: The sum is 12178 but uncompressed responce size is 28879